# Why listing of items is empty in calling method of the component?

Tags: laravel-livewire

with livewire 2 I have listing of items ($itemDataRows var) and I need for any item show checkbox ($selectedItems var) and
"Select all" button and clicking on this button all items must be selected. I do :

```
class CrudItems extends Component
{
    private $itemDataRows = [];
    public $selectedItems = [];
    ...

    public function render()
    {
        ...
        $this->itemDataRows   = Item
            ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ...
            ->paginate($backend_per_page);

        return view('livewire.admin.items.crud-items', [
            'itemDataRows'    => $this->itemDataRows,
            'item_rows_count' => $this->item_rows_count
        ])->layout('layouts.admin');
        }
    }


    public function calcSelectedItemsCount()
    {
        $ret= 0;
        foreach( $this->selectedItems as $next_key=>$next_value ) {
            if($next_value) {
                $ret++;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public function selectAllItems()
    {
        $this->selectedItems= [];
        \Log::info(  dump($this->itemDataRows, ' -0 $this->itemDataRows selectAllItems::') );
        // INL OG FILE_I SEE THAT ARRAY ABOVE IS EMPTY!!!
        foreach( $this->itemDataRows as $nextItemDataRow ) {
            $this->selectedItems[$nextItemDataRow->id] = true;
            \Log::info(  dump($this->selectedItems, ' -$this->selectedItems INSIDE selectAllItems::') );
        }
        \Log::info(  dump($this->selectedItems, ' -$this->selectedItems selectAllItems::') );
    }
```

and in template :

```
        $selectedItems::{{ var_dump($selectedItems) }}<hr>
        $itemDataRows::{{ $itemDataRows }}
/* $selectedItems is filled ok when I click on checkboxes , but $itemDataRows shows empty var, though I filled items listing below */

  @foreach ($itemDataRows as $item)
    <tr>
      <td class=" whitespace-nowrap  ">
          <x-jet-checkbox id="is_reopen" type="checkbox" class="editor_checkbox_field ml-4" title="On saving editor will be opened"
          wire:model="selectedItems.{{ $item->id }}"/>
     </td>
```

Is something wrong with definition of $itemDataRows ? Why $itemDataRows is empty in selectAllItems method, but on my template all items are visible ok....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Livewire you can pass the data via the class variables. And in the mount function you can fill the variable. For Example.

**Important Note:** The Class Vars must be public!

```
public $selectedItems = [];

public function mount(): void
{
    $this->selectedItems = ['data' => 'Hello World'];
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.admin.items.crud-items')->layout('layouts.admin');
}
```

### Update

This must have something to do with the Livewire Lifecyle. Every Livewire component goes through a lifecycle. Lifecycle hooks allow you to run code at any stage of the component's lifecycle or before updating certain properties. In your case, use the mount hook.

You initialise the variable itemDataRows in the render function. A request then calls the method selectAllItems. There you have to initialise itemDataRows again, because the state is no longer there during render or mount.

**Solution:** create a method getItemDataRows()

```
private getItemDataRows()
{
   $this->itemDataRows => Item::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ...
            ->paginate($backend_per_page);
}
```

then you can call those in the render method and in the selectAllItems method too.

```
public function selectAllItems()
{
    $this->selectedItems= [];
    $this->itemDataRows => $this->getItemDataRows();
    ...
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have  $selectedItems public, but I can not get why in function selectAllItems $this->itemDataRow is empty - I fill it in render as I need to change any filter input on form to rearead data from db\

Comment: @PetroGromovo take a look to the answear. I updated. I think that will be work.

Comment: That does not work as in selectAllItems I call $this->getItemDataRows(), but it returns nothing.
I tried as :
private getItemDataRows()
{
   $this->itemDataRows => $this->itemDataRows;
   return $this->itemDataRows;
}

but it does not work anyway.
Also assigning $this->itemDataRow to itself seems tricky. Can it have some effect? Please check.

Comment: @PetroGromovo sorry, my mistake. i meant that it should be in the function:
`private getItemDataRows()
{
   $this->itemDataRows => Item::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ...
            ->paginate($backend_per_page);;
}` I updated in the answear below.

Comment: @PetroGromovo that must work ;-)

Comment: Thanks!
Looks like it work, but could you please exapline and give to docs link as for yours:
because the state is no longer there during render or mount
?
After mount->render were completed all data I got in them are lost ?
And that is why I have 2 similar blocks of code :
   $this->itemDataRows => Item::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ...
            ->paginate($backend_per_page);

Comment: Calling of selectAllHostels send additive request to db. I would like to avoid it, but it is not critical...            
I have worked with vuejs and I kept user's data in vuex/localStorage.
I supposed that livewire keeps all data in some intenal storage and any time I can read these datas, say by click from form.
That is not so?

Comment: @PetroGromovo It would be nice. i think you can already put it in a session on the server side. but it is ok to request the data on the request. here the link to the hooks: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks